# Iterate through a const vector of pointers with auto

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, ranged-loops

Let's say I have the following const vector of pointer :

```
const std::vector<Component*> components;
```

and I want to iterate through it and only calling a method on one element of this vector. Is it correct to do :

```
for (const auto& item : components) {
  method(item);
}
```

What is the difference with using :

```
for (auto item : components) {
  method(item);
}
```

with :

```
void method(Components* component);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct to do

It depends on you.

For the 1st case, the type of `item` will be `Component* const&`, which is a reference bound to the element of the `vector`.

For the 2nd case, the type of `item` will be `Component*`, which (i.e. the pointer itself) is copied from the the element of the `vector`.

The parameter type of `method` is `Component*`, means passing the pointer by value/copy, then there's no actual difference between the 2 cases. And for pointer (as built-in type), just `auto item : components` is fine here.

Comment: Then If I do not want the pointer to be copied, first case is better right ? Do you know a better solution to iterate on such a vector ? (if I want to prevent copy and if I do not want to modify object)

Comment: @klaus Yes. But for build-in types including pointers avoiding copy doesn't make much sense. And, what do you want the type of `item` to be?

Comment: I want to be a pointer to Component. I think `for (auto& item : components)` is enough and if one day my vector becomes a vector of Components (and not Components*), it will still works... right ?

Comment: @klaus Well, then just `auto item : ...` seems fine. `auto&` makes `item` a reference to the element, if you change it point to another thing, the element is changed too. If that's what you want you should use reference.